# Mistake in paper about Bat Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I need help from a person that knows the so called bat algorithm well. I have a problem with the third equation listed in the [publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4170v1) of Xin-She Yang from 2010. There it says that the velocity is updated adding:

> (current_position - best_position) * random _number.

Why is it (current_position - best_position) and not (best_position - current_position)? I can't think of any case where the proposed variant is consistently better than the intuitively more appealing second variant. (best_position - current_position) can be interpreted as making a step with random step size into the direction of the currently best solution. The variant from the paper is the exact opposite, i.e. making steps into the direction that lead into the exact opposite direction than the one to the best.

In another [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.05854) that I found, they did switch both variables, i.e. they are using the second more intuitive variant. Did they understand it wrong, or did the author make an mistake?

Can anyone explain this to me, please? Thanks soo much in Advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about the mathematics of the algorithm rather than implementation. Consider asking at [math.se].

Comment: The cited publication of Xin-She Yang seems erroneous. For one, the equations (3) and (4) on page 4 have a cyclic dependency of vᵢt and xᵢt.